# Error drools - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/drools/event/KnowledgeRuntimeEventManager

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, drools

I'm developing an eclipse plugin "jass" using the drools engine to make inferences on some concepts and displays them using an editor implemented with GEF

I added drools 5.5.0 in the build path. (knowledge-api.jar, drools-compiler.jar drolls-core.jar ecc.)

To test the operation of the engine I created a main method that retrieval engine and works well. Inverce if I run the plugin I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/drools/event/KnowledgeRuntimeEventManager
    at org.envt.tool.jass.wizards.FilePage.finish(FilePage.java:191)
    at org.envt.tool.jass.wizards.JassEditorWizard.performFinish(JassEditorWizard.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:827)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$New.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1029)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:923)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.drools.event.KnowledgeRuntimeEventManager
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Can any one help how to solve this problem 
Thanks

Comment: which drools jar are you using ?

Comment: I used jar created  Drools runtime automatically.
drools-core.jar
jnowledge-api-jar
ecc.

Comment: Add the Drools jars to the classpath in use when you start Eclipse, which is an entirely different thing than the build paths used when building an application under Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider updating to Drools 6.x. The reason being that I assume an Eclipse plugin's runtime is an OSGI environment and I do not know if Drools 5.x is OSGI compatible, whereas Drools 6.x is definitely OSGI ready.